# Facebook Developer - Privacy Policy URL

Tags: android, facebook

I got Privacy Policies Notice in my Email for one of my Facebook App asking me to update my privacy policy URL.
When I click the policy link, I am not able to find the privacy policy URL and strangely when I search my application and try to open it, it says "The page you requested was not found". Is my Application deactivated? Is that the reason that there is no Privacy Policy URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ADD a privacy policy to your application, it doesn't have one. The link should take you to your app configuration page where you add a link to your app's privacy policy.

Comment: But there is no link in my FaceBook developer account, there is no URL..!!